# Background glitch on keyboard closure

Tags: android, background, keyboard

I'm facing a situation with a little complex fragment layout xml of mine,

So the hierarchy follows as:

RelativeLayout (no background)
--ScrollView (fillViewPort=true, scrollbars=none)
----FrameLayout (no background)
------LinearLayout (no background)
--------RelativeLayout (background color of gray)
----------EditText
...

So when the edittext clicked it opens soft keyboard (as expected), and when back press or some click block which hides keyboard with following method:

```
try {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) GlobalApplication.getInstance().getCurrentActivity().getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(GlobalApplication.getInstance().getCurrentActivity().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (e.getMessage() != null)
            Log.d("KeyboardError", e.getMessage());
    }
```

The problem is I've a red background for the activity and when the hiding keyboard action happens, I'm seeing the activity's background instead of the gray background of the RelativeLayout, and it's happening like a glitch or stuck. After awhile it comes back to normal and shows proper background.

Thanks for help, cheers.

Comment: Specify which version of Android you are using. It will be helpful in finding the answer

Comment: it's happening on several versions of android, 4.4.2  5.1  6.0  7.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this in your base activity onCreate() after super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

or

Add these lines in your manifest under your activity tag

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
```